# AngularJS - Get elements in a factory when elements are in a ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I'm trying to catch each "noscript" tag in my view.
I create a function in my factory, and call it when the controller is launched.

Here's my function :

```
angular.forEach(angular.element(document.querySelector('noscript')), function (value, key) {
// some code
```

The problem is that the "noscript" elements are in a ng-include, and it seems that the include is launched after the controller ..
Then, I can't catch the elements !

What is the best way to do that ?
Thanks by advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a directive that exposes a function for handling `noscript` tags within an include. You could call the function via the `onload` attribute of the `ng-include`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/REYhN/

Please note, that you should avoid doing DOM manipulation in controllers. That's what directives are for: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Answer (score 0):

Get it !

I called my controllers in my routes.. I read somewhere that it isn't a good practice.
Understand why now.

The solution is to call your controller in the partial via ng-controller.
And then, you can do whatever you want and get every dom elements :).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to catch the noscript tags, but have you considered using modernizr instead of noscript tags?

> [w3c noscript](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20120329/the-noscript-element.html#the-noscript-element)
>
> The noscript element is a blunt instrument. Sometimes, scripts might
>   be enabled, but for some reason the page's script might fail. For this
>   reason, it's generally better to avoid using noscript, and to instead
>   design the script to change the page from being a scriptless page to a
>   scripted page on the fly...

Comment: The question isn't there ^^. I refactor the jQuery code to make it in Angular.